# how to constrain two parameters by making one is always smaller than another? In Rjags

Tags: data-fitting, jags

I use an exponential function to fit a learning curve. Here is the function form:

```
y = (w - alpha) * e^(-x / gamma) + alpha,
```

where `w` is the initial threshold before learning, `alpha` is the final threshold after learning, `gamma` is learning rate, `x` is the learning days, `y` is the threshold. 
I have one question: how to make `alpha` is always smaller than `w` in fitting by Rjags?
Thanks!
Pan

Comment: fit some date from a experiment by jags

Comment: w, alpha, and gamma must be positive value.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Version**
I think the first version gave a clear idea how to solve this simple constrictions in a rather simple way. So here we have the formula

```
y = (w - alpha) * e^(-x / gamma) + alpha
```

and we want that `w`, `alpha`, and `gamma` greater or equal zero.
This is equivalent to a positive offset, a positive decay constant, and a positive amplitude.
As before, this can be achieved by a simple substitution

```
alpha = beta^2
gamma = epsilon^2
w - alpha = tau^2
```

We just fit

```
y = tau^2 * e^( -x / epsilon**2 ) + beta**2
```

i.e., hence, a positive offset, a positive decay constant, and a positive amplitude.

At the end we just recalculate

```
alpha = beta^2
gamma = epsilon^2
w = tau^2 + beta^2
```

The errors are obtained by [standard error propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty), where correlation might play a role for `w`

Comment: Thanks! But w, alpha, and gamma must be positive value. So even we make alpha=w-beta*2, we still need to make beta*2<w. Replacing alpha by another parameter can not work.

Comment: @Pan As my question in the post suggests, negative alpha changes things, so your first statement is justified. Your second point , however, is not. So let me see how to change accordingly.

Comment: I think I figure it out. I use some code like this: alpha~dnorm (mu, sd) T(0, w).

Comment: @Pan Well, your comment is a bit cryptic as no `mu`, `sd` or `T` were mentioned up to now, but if it works for you I am glad to here. Though I dont get why you couldn't use the posted solution. Cheers